# how to give color to table tr?

Tags: php, css

Hello i have a table with some fields like
[image]

here i want make colors for table entire rows..means if ASR value is 75 to 100 should get one color and 50 to 75 should get another color and below 50 should get another color.

and here is my php code

```
<table width="75%" border="1">
<tr>
<td align="center">channel no</td>
<td align="center">IP</td>
<td align="center">Total calls</td>
<td align="center">Connected calls</td>
<td align="center">Disconnected calls</td>
<td align="center">Duration</td>
<td align="center">ASR</td>
<td align="center">ACD</td>

</tr> 
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

//$minutes = gmdate("H:i:s", $row['tduration']);
echo "<tr>

<td>".$row['channel']."&nbsp;</td>
<td>".$row['ip']."&nbsp;</td>
<td>".$row['totalcalls']."&nbsp;</td>";

if ($row['totalcalls']>1){
$sql1    = "SELECT count(duration) as count  FROM gateways where duration=0 and ip='".$_POST['ip']."' and channel='".$row['channel']. "' and (connect_datetime BETWEEN ' ".$_POST['toval']." ' and '".$_POST['fromval']."'  or disconnect_datetime BETWEEN ' ".$_POST['toval']." ' and '".$_POST['fromval']."' ) Group by channel";

$result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $link);
$norow=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
$attenedcalls=($row['totalcalls']-$norow['count']);
echo "<td>".$attenedcalls."&nbsp;</td>";
$disconnectedcalls=($row['totalcalls']-$attenedcalls);
echo "<td>".$disconnectedcalls."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "   <td>".$row['tduration']."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>".(($attenedcalls/$row['totalcalls'])*100)."</td>";
}else{

    echo "<td>".$row['totalcalls']."</td>";

    echo "<td>100</td>";

}

$minutes = gmdate("H:i:s", ($row['tduration']/$attenedcalls));
echo "   <td>".$minutes."&nbsp;</td>
</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You should look into CSS which you can use to easily set colors. All you would need to do is to set a style for each row and the CSS will do the rest.

Comment: Your first row should be `<tr><th>Channel No</th></tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
<table width="75%" border="1">
<tr>
<td align="center">channel no</td>
<td align="center">IP</td>
<td align="center">Total calls</td>
<td align="center">Connected calls</td>
<td align="center">Disconnected calls</td>
<td align="center">Duration</td>
<td align="center">ASR</td>
<td align="center">ACD</td>

</tr> 
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$color = '';
if ($row['totalcalls']>1){
    $sql1    = "SELECT count(duration) as count  FROM gateways where duration=0 and ip='".$_POST['ip']."' and channel='".$row['channel']. "' and (connect_datetime BETWEEN ' ".$_POST['toval']." ' and '".$_POST['fromval']."'  or disconnect_datetime BETWEEN ' ".$_POST['toval']." ' and '".$_POST['fromval']."' ) Group by channel";

    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $link);
    $norow=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
    $attenedcalls=($row['totalcalls']-$norow['count']);
    $asr = (($attenedcalls/$row['totalcalls'])*100);
    if($asr >= 75 && $asr <=100 ){
        $color = 'red';
    }else if($asr >= 50 && $asr < 75){
        $color = 'cyan';
    }else if($asr < 50){
        $color = 'blue';
    }
}
//$minutes = gmdate("H:i:s", $row['tduration']);
echo "<tr style='background-color : ".$color."'>

<td>".$row['channel']."&nbsp;</td>
<td>".$row['ip']."&nbsp;</td>
<td>".$row['totalcalls']."&nbsp;</td>";

if ($row['totalcalls']>1){

echo "<td>".$attenedcalls."&nbsp;</td>";
$disconnectedcalls=($row['totalcalls']-$attenedcalls);
echo "<td>".$disconnectedcalls."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "   <td>".$row['tduration']."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>".$asr."</td>";
}else{

    echo "<td>".$row['totalcalls']."</td>";

    echo "<td>100</td>";

}

$minutes = gmdate("H:i:s", ($row['tduration']/$attenedcalls));
echo "   <td>".$minutes."&nbsp;</td>
</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `while` loop so that you compute the ASR value before emitting the `<tr>` tag. Use that value to select a class according to the classification you have set up, and emit a tag of the form `<tr class=foo>` where `foo` is the class name you have selected. Then it’s just a matter of writing CSS rules for the classes, using class selectors like `tr.foo`.

(Provided that you have not set color on the `td` cells. If you have, you need to use selectors like `tr.foo td` to override such settings.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 [...]  
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 $asrVal=(($attenedcalls/$row['totalcalls'])*100);
 if($asrVal>=50 && $asrVal <=75) $class="from50to75";
 if($asrVal>=75 && $asrVal <=100) $class="from75to100";
 if($asrVal<50) $class="below50";
 //$minutes = gmdate("H:i:s", $row['tduration']); 
 echo "<tr class='$class'> 
 [...]
```

then add:

```
<style>
tr.from50to75 td{background-color:red;}
tr.from75to100 td{background-color:green;}
tr.below50 td{background-color:blue;}
</style>
```